# react js :fetch data from inner array and load it to state

Tags: javascript

i have a api with peoples i am tring to dispaly names of people

```js
"peoples": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "mainModule": "bonding",
        "description": "some random description 2",

        "persons": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "hari",
                "completed": false
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "meenu",
                "completed": false
            }
        ]


 "id": 1,
        "mainModule": "bonding2",
        "description": "some random description 2",


   "persons": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "jisa",
                "completed": false
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "stepy",
                "completed": false
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

This is my data in api

I am using axios to set  a state called items

```js
 axios
      .get(
        "url",
        config
      )
      .then((res) => {

        console.log(res.data.peoples)//this works
        console.log(res.data.peoples.persons);//here i am getting error
      

        this.setState({ items: res.data.peoples.persons}); error
}
```

I am trying to pass persons so I can map person names in JSX

i have changed the code pls help

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow! As you can see in your first snippet you have an array inside `peoples` so the correct way to access it would be:

`res.data.peoples[0].persons`

Hope this solves your problem. You can read more about it in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

*edit:*

If you would like to iterate over persons you can do this:

```js
res.data.peoples.map(person => (
  <div key={person.id}>{person.name}</div>
));
```

Remember you must pass a unique key prop to the component so React can create and mantain the list correctly. More info about it in the [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: what to do i have 100 of persons is there a sytax to itrate throgh all

Comment: I edited my answer with a JSX example for you. Let me know if that helps you :)

Comment: i am not able to  map directlty  res . i have to set state items  in order to map it

Answer (score 0):

`res.data.peoples` is an array so you should iterate over it. It doesn't have persons property, it has [0], [1] etc. Try to log  res.data.peoples[0].persons

Comment: what to do i have 100 of persons is there a sytax to itrate throgh all

Comment: I suspect, you have to accumulate all persons for all people with **Array.reduce**

Answer (score 0):

From the sample data you showed, peoples is an array. So to access persons, you should be able to access it using the following, for example if you want to access the first element of the array:

```
res.data.peoples[0].persons
```

Otherwise, if you want to access it as res.data.peoples.persons then you have to change your API output such that it is like so :

```js
"peoples": {
        "id": 2,
        "mainModule": "bonding",
        "description": "some random description 2",

        "persons": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "hari",
                "completed": false
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "meenu",
                "completed": false
            }
        ]
    }
```